# vaadin resize columns table from another table

Tags: vaadin

I have 2 CustomTables with same column names. They are created using expandratio width. 
I added resizecolumnlisteners to them so when user column in table1 resize also table2 and vice versa. Problem is when resizing with

```
List<Values> list;// list of objects in table;
table1.addresizeColumnListener(new resizeColumnListener(){
private void resizeColumn(Event)
{
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
    table2.setColumnWidth(list.get(i), table1.getColumnWidth(list.get(i)));
    }
}
```

in table changes only column where listener is fired all others dont change, only when i click any column again all column's widths in table2 is set from table1.

Answer (score 0):

I have too low stackoverflow reputation level to add a comment - so I'm writing this answer.

First of all: Which version of Vaadin do you use? I can't find the function which you used:

```
table1.addresizeColumnListener(...)
```

In Vaadin latest documentation is [addColumnResizeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#addColumnResizeListener(com.vaadin.ui.Table.ColumnResizeListener)).

And I have doubt why you want change size of all column after notification that *one* column has been changed? I imagine that after each column size change the *Table.ColumnResizeEvent* should be emit.

Comment: it is my mistake. function i use  is addColumnResizeListener()

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is that when you re-size something in the browser, it will not get sent to the server straight away. The update to the server is sent to the server along with the next update request. That is why you get the delayed update to the UI (if I understood it correctly).

To fix this you can try the code below. Notice the **setImmediate(true)**. This will basically tells Vaadin that you want any update to the table to be sent to the server immediately when the user modifies the table properties.

Try this:

```
    table1.setImmediate(true);
    table1.addColumnResizeListener(new ColumnResizeListener(){
        @Override
        public void columnResize(ColumnResizeEvent event) {
                table2.setColumnWidth(event.getPropertyId(), event.getCurrentWidth());          
        }
    });
    table2.setImmediate(true);
    table2.addColumnResizeListener(new ColumnResizeListener(){
        @Override
        public void columnResize(ColumnResizeEvent event) {
                table1.setColumnWidth(event.getPropertyId(), event.getCurrentWidth());          
        }
    });
```